# How to access complex tuples/maps elixir

Tags: maps, tuples, elixir

How can i access values of aaa, xxx, yyy & zzz from into separate variables, as it does seems mix of maps/tuple.

```
{{: xxx, %{yyy: 'something', zzz: 'test'}, {aaa: 'best'}}}
```

Sorry guys for troubling you, i got that working as

```
iex(1)> {a, b, c} = {: xxx, %{yyy: 'something', zzz: 'test'}, {aaa: 'best'}}
{: xxx, %{yyy: 'something', zzz: 'test'}, {aaa: 'test'}}
iex(2)> a
:xxx
iex(3)> b
%{yyy: 'something', zzz: 'test'}
iex(4)> b[:zzz]
'test'
```

thanks anyways to all.

Comment: Where did :message come from in that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can even pattern-match on map keys:

```
iex(1)> {a, %{zzz: b}, %{aaa: c}} = {:xxx, %{yyy: "something", zzz: "test"}, %{aaa: "best"}}
{:xxx, %{yyy: "something", zzz: "test"}, %{aaa: "best"}}
iex(2)> a
:xxx
iex(3)> b
"test"
iex(4)> c
"best"
```

See http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/7.html

Btw, in Elixir, single- and doublequotes have different meaning (charlist vs. binary). If you don't really need singlequotes (charlist), use doublequotes everywhere - binary is the default string format in Elixir (see [String docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html))